# How to automatically turn off wifi on Windows 10 during certain time of day?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I like to automatically turn off my Windows 10 laptop's wifi each day at 10pm and turn it on at 11:30pm. Note that I do not want to turn off my home wifi, only the wifi of this laptop.

I see a suggestion in the comment of [this solution](https://www.nextofwindows.com/windows-10-tip-how-to-schedule-to-turn-on-wifi-connection-automatically#:~:text=Open%20Settings%20app%2C%20click%20Network,4%20hours%2C%20or%201%20day.) like this:

> Seems like you’d have a better chance using Task Scheduler with a
>   PowerShell command like
>
> Enable-NetAdapter -Name ‘Wi-Fi’-Confirm:$false

But it is not clear to me how to do that.

Could you help how to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to follow these steps:

- open up task scheduler
- create a task, when you get to the `Action` step, choose `start a program`
- on the `start a program` step, type `powershell` in the `program/script` box, and type `-command  "enable-netadapter -name wifi -confirm:$False"` in the `add arguments` box.
- finish creating the task, then right click on it and go to its properties, then enable the option `run whether user is logged on or not` and `run with highest privileges`.

Please refer to screenshots below.

[image]
[image]